# Weblogic 12C - Unable to get a web.xml's <env-entry> JNDI entry

Tags: java, weblogic, jndi, web.xml, weblogic12c

I'm trying to get a `<env-entry>` entry I defnined in the `web.xml` of a war inside a .ear deployed application in Weblogic 12c :

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>java:app/test</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>1111111</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

and, in my code :

```
Object test = InitialContext.doLookup("java:app/test");
System.out.println(test);
```

An exception is throwned :

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up /app/test in /app/webapp/xxx/yyy/1243828215.; remaining name '/app/test'
```

Weblogic seems to modify something in the JNDI resolution process : "xxx/yyy" is the context-root of my application in Weblogic and "1243828215" is a random number!

Any idea how I can defined the `<env-entry>` entries so they can be retrieved using `InitialContext.doLookup()`?

Comment: What happens when you use `<env-entry-name>app/test</env-entry-name>` `InitialContext.doLookup("app/test");` I do not think you need to pre-pend `java:` as that is already done for you automatically by the container

Comment: Sadly : `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'app.test' didn't find subcontext 'app'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'app/test'"`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@Resource(name = "java:app/test")
private String test;
```